# ActionCable not run in background job rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable, rescue

My project use rescue to run background job. 
I use actioncable in a job to notify user when the job finish. but it not running when use perform_later, but perform_now => it work ok.

My job:

```
class FetchExternalDataJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform
    # logic here
    ActionCable.server.broadcast "some_channel", message: "finish job"
  end
end
```

Call job:

```
class RoomsController < ApplicationController

  def show
    FetchExternalDataJob.perform_later
  end
```

Channel javascript:

```
App.fetch_data = App.cable.subscriptions.create "FetchDataChannel",
  received: (data) ->
    console.log("job finished")
```

Comment: Perhaps you're missing the worker to actually pick jobs off the queue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you set up redis as your adapter in `cable.yml` yet?

ei:

```
development:
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://localhost:6379/1
```

Comment: This is correct, except that i used the url as `//localhost:6379/0` instead of `//localhost:6379/1`